# How to send text from Python to DeepL desktop app

Tags: python, desktop-application, deepl

I know DeepL has a library to send text to their servers for translation, but I want to use their desktop app which has no internet dependency.

The Desktop app has this feature where if you press Ctrl+C+C, it will put that highlighted text into the DeepL app and it works from there.

I was wondering if it's possible from python automatically send text over to the DeepL Desktop app this way.

Comment: Send from where? What is "Python"? From CLI, from browser, desktop app?

Comment: From a python script, I'm using whisper AI python to detect what im saying and storing them in a string variable. I want to send it over to the DeepL desktop app since if they're detecting highlighted text, python should be able to somehow fake it to seem like the string variable is what is highlighted right?

Comment: You should include that info in the question. Anyways, honestly, I don't think so. At least it's not something that people would use any frequently. Maybe with help of something like `win32api`. Your best bet though is e.g. calling an AHK script that launches DeepL for you and enters the text. Or maybe some Python automation library is able to do so, not sure. Very easy to do it this way.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info, and ya i'll try to be more descriptive in the future.